# How do electrons get kinetic energy in a circuit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, electricity, electrons

Consider the following circuit with its switch closed.
[image: Electric-Circuit]

Electrons start moving from the negative terminal and then move throughout the circuit, I have two questions.

1. From where do these electrons get their their kinetic energy. Since we know that when a force is applied the object on which work is done gains energy in the similar way these electrons get energy to move but from what?(what is applies this force)
2. In this circuit there is a bulb, it needs energy to light up, so kinetic energy from electrons might have changed to light and heat energy. Due to loss of kinetic energy shouldn't the velocity of electron decrease?

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. I think you should give a look to [this](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html#light)

Comment: I would suggest that you use the Physics Stack Exchange search engine using the words [electrons energy wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=energy+electrons+wire) to find the answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The electrons in a circuit gain their kinetic energy from the electric field created by a voltage difference across the circuit. When a voltage is applied to a circuit, it creates an electric field that causes the free electrons in the circuit to move in a particular direction, from the negative terminal to the positive terminal.

Yes, the velocity of electron does decrease but there is a constant potential difference across a circuit so even if electron loses it's kinetic energy there is always electric field which pushes electron and it gains kinetic energy again(at least that's what I understand)

Comment: Thank You very much. I now understand it totally

Answer (score -1):

The electrons are there in the conductor. But when a potential difference is applied by preferably a battery, the potential difference does the work $W = ne\,\Delta V$ with $n$ the number of electrons, $e$ the charge of an electron and $V$ the applied potential difference.

By Work-Energy Theorem, we know that that $W=\Delta KE$ (kinetic energy). We also know that $W=ne\,\Delta V$ and $KE=\frac{1}{2}nmv^2$, with $m$ the mass of an electron and $v$ its velocity.

By equating both the equations by substituting, we get:
$$ne\,\Delta V=\frac{1}{2}nmv^2$$
calculating $v$ its value comes out to be:
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{2e\,\Delta V}{m}}$$
This is the velocity which provides the kinetic energy to electrons.